# Creating multiple lists inside a loop

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I want to dynamically create `ArrayList`s inside a loop like:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    List<myItems> d(i) = new ArrayList<myItems>();
}
```

All I want to do is create 3 such lists inside a loop. Can I do that?

Comment: Yes, you can do that (you accidentally typed `new` twice) but it's not accomplishing anything.  You're just creating a new List every time through the loop without using it.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: *"Can I do that?"*  You have my permission.

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic arraylist?

Comment: @jahroy I want to create 3 different arraylist's like d1,d2 and d3 inside a loop.

Comment: Your current code creates 3 different ArrayLists, it just assigns them all to the same variable, so each one gets overwritten.  If you want 3 different Lists, you will need 3 different variables.

Comment: Actually... after a closer look (and your edit) your code is not valid.  It will not compile and does not follow syntax rules.

Comment: @user1563221 You would probably solve that instead by making an ArrayList of ArrayList or a Map of ArrayList.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is what you are looking for.

```
ArrayList<myItem>[] d = (ArrayList<myItem>[]) new ArrayList[3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    d[i] = new ArrayList<myItems>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No: variable names are merely a convenience for the programmer and are not kept track of after your code is compiled, so that kind of "dynamic variable naming" is not allowed. You will have to find another way to keep track of your lists, such as a `Map<String, List<Item>>` that maps string identifiers to lists:

```
Map<String, List<Item>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Item>>()
map.put("d1", new ArrayList<Item>());
...
```

To then access the list corresponding to `"d1"`, for example you can just use `map.get("d1")`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a `List<List<MyItem>>` instead and fill it in the loop

Answer (score 0):

If you do this:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
  List<myItems> d = new ArrayList<myItems>();
}
```

You will create a new array list three times. But each time you will store it to a newly created reference `d` and once you leave the scope of the `for` loop, that reference will vanish.

What you may be looking for is this:

```
List<List<myItems>> d = new ArrayList<List<myItems)>();
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
  d.add(new ArrayList<myItems>());
}
```

This creates a nested list:

```
someListOfListsOfMyItems
  subListOfMyItems
    someMyItem
    anotherMyItem
  subListOfMyItems
    someOtherMyItem
    anotherOtherMyItem
  subListOfMyItems
    yetSomeOtherMyItem
    yetAnotherMyItem
```

Each sublist can be accessed like so:

```
d.get(indexOfSublist);
```

Comment: how to add new item to the sublist? @Nathaniel Ford

Comment: `d.get(idx).add(aNewItem);`, where `idx` is the index of the sublist you're adding to. @ohlala